# Yii2 password hash

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I'd like to know how password hash is generated?

```
// This is my code:

$email="mail@example.net";
$password="mypassword";

// How to get password_hash variable?

$user = User::find()->where(['email'=>$email, 'password_hash'=>$password_hash])->one();
if(isset($user)){
   echo "there is";
} else {
 "Sorry!";  
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `User::find()->where(['email'=>$email, 'password_hash'=>$password_hash])->one();` This habit does not secure with sql injection. We should find model then call validatePassword function to validate user model. Reference Pheagey's answer.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html Is how passwords are handled in Yii 2. Unless you're a crypto expert DO NOT try to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function verifyPassword($password)
    {
        if(md5($password) === $this->password)
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;
        //return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }

  public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        // hash new password if set
        if ($this->newPassword) {
            //$this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->newPassword);
            $this->password = md5($this->newPassword);
        }

        // convert ban_time checkbox to date
        if ($this->ban_time) {
            $this->ban_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }

        // ensure fields are null so they won't get set as empty string
        $nullAttributes = ["email", "username", "ban_time", "ban_reason"];
        foreach ($nullAttributes as $nullAttribute) {
            $this->$nullAttribute = $this->$nullAttribute ? $this->$nullAttribute : null;
        }

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
```

Comment: ^- MD5 is a terrible choice.

Answer (score -4):

I use hash with md5 but i create function in user model

```
    public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return $this->PASSWORD === md5($password);
}
```

Comment: md5 is highly insecure.  I would either use PHP's new built-in password_hash function or yii\base\Security::generatePasswordHash.

Comment: This is the answer:

`$user = User::find()->where(['email'=>$email])->one();
if(!$user){
   // Wrong email
} elseif (!Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $user->password_hash)) {
   // Invalid password
} else {
  // Ok
}`

Comment: ...Please tell me you no longer do this. Use the built in crypto methods. MD5 will get you compromised.

A simple MD4/SHA1 hash is no longer a secure form of encryption.